# VS Code TSX and post-return formatting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

We're trying to get some formatting parity between VS Code and VS w/ Resharper and have gotten pretty close except I cannot figure out how to get VS Code to format TSX files and properly format around the returns statement:

**Expected:**

```
public render() {
    return <div>
               <div>Test</div>
               {this.props.Model.arr.map((value, index) => {
                   return <div className="test" key={index}>
                              <div>{value.test}</div>
                          </div>;
               })}
           </div>;
}
```

**Actual**:

```
public render() {
    return <div>
        <div>Test</div>
        {this.props.Model.arr.map((value, index) => {
            return <div className="test" key={index}>
                <div>{value.test}</div>
            </div>;
        })}
    </div>;
}
```

Is this possible? Bug in VS Code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible? Bug in VS Code maybe?

Not with default TypeScript settings. The formatting is provided by TypeScript (not a vscode bug).

## Fix

Use https://prettier.io/. It [supports TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tools/prettier.html).